# brew error: /usr/local/bin/brew:34:in `<': comparison of String with Float failed (ArgumentError)

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to get brew going on my OS X 10.7.5 and having some issues. My brew install is now broken.

```
$ brew doctor
/usr/local/bin/brew:34:in `<': comparison of String with Float failed (ArgumentError)
from /usr/local/bin/brew:34
```

My best guess is that I managed to kill brew somehow by running:

```
$ sudo chown -R myusername:admin /usr/local
```

Thoughts?

My plan is to simply uninstall brew and start from scratch.

p.s. The brew version is 0.9.5

```
$ brew -v
0.9.5
```

Comment: Starting over sounds like the right idea. Trying to debug this is probably more hassle then it's worth. On the other hand, if you want to, you should try `nano /usr/local/bin/brew` and see what line 34 is.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
vi +34 /usr/local/bin/brew
```

This in order to see what that comparison is. I had the same problem here, and it was trying to compare if `MACOS_VERSION < 10.5`.  Since I'm using Lion, I just commented that `if` and got it working:

```
=begin
if MACOS_VERSION < 10.5
  abort <<-EOABORT.undent
    Homebrew requires Leopard or higher. For Tiger support, see:
    http://github.com/sceaga/homebrew/tree/tiger
  EOABORT
end
=end
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by simply "checking out" a "fresh" version of `/usr/local/bin/brew`....

`cd /usr/local && git checkout origin/master -- bin/brew`

then a requisite visit to the `brew doctor`.  ouch.